# issue with high recall, low precision after oversampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, oversampling, smote

I have a classification problem with class imbalance and after the oversampling, I get high recall ,accuracy and roc (around 0.85) while my precision and f1 is fairly low(0.50). I have used every kind of smote and undersammpling but I never get to achieve some balance between precision and recall.I have done some params tuning but when I try to increase my precision, my recall drops of course. Do you have any suggestions as to how i can increase my precision whilst not hurting the recall too much?

Comment: Are you oversampling your test/validation set?

Comment: No, only my train set.